# Is there an article describing how to implement transport provider of the early UNIX?

Tags: networking, operating-system

I am writing a simple OS with the network feature. But i don't know how to begin the networt part. the Linux Device Driver is not easy to read.

Could you give me some matearials or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [lwIP](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/) - A Lightweight TCP/IP stack. It implements all necessary functionality to send/receive UDP datagrams and to establish TCP connections.

lwIP is licenced under the BSD licence, so you may use it even in non-opensource project.

Comment: but it just implements the protocal layer, not the netcard device driver. i need the device driver part. thanks.

Comment: then take a look at `grub` souces - it has network support so you probably will be able to find something useful